# Heroku deployment: main route no longer working (worked at localhost)

Tags: reactjs, express, heroku, next.js

I have a weird issue when my code is deployed to Heroku. At localhost I can access all routes back and forth. After deployed onto Heroku, the main landing page can still render once user gets authenticated (i.e. `/homes/main`). But I cannot navigate back to `/homes/main` once navigating away from it (e.g. after going to `/homes/new` or `/homes/pay`). The only way to navigate back is to change the browser URL. I used Express & Passport for single sign-on and next-router for routing the react frontend.

Even worse, programmatic routing by event handling to `/homes/main` is not working either.

**routes.js:**

```
const routes = require('next-routes')();
routes
  .add('/homes/main', '/homes/main')
  .add('/homes/new', '/homes/new')
  .add('/homes/pay', '/homes/pay');
module.exports = routes;
```

**server.js:**

```
const express = require("express");
const keys = require("./config/keys");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const cookieSession = require('cookie-session');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

const passport = require('passport');
require('./models/Users');
require("./services/passport");

mongoose.connect(keys.mongoDBURI);

const app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(cookieSession({
  maxAge: 30*24*60*60*1000,
  keys: [keys.cookieKey]
  }
));

app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

require("./routes/authRoute")(app);

const next = require('next');
const routes = require('./routes');
const next_app = next({
  dev: process.env.NODE_ENV !=='production'
});
const handler = routes.getRequestHandler(next_app);

next_app.prepare().then(()=>{
  const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;
  app.use(handler).listen(PORT, (err)=>{
    if(err) throw err;
    console.log(`Ready on port: ${PORT}`);
  });
});
```

**package.json:**

```
....
"scripts": {
  "start": "NODE_ENV=production node server.js",
  "dev": "node server.js",
  "build": "next build",
  "heroku-postbuild": "next build"
}
....
```

**My directories:**

```
/pages
/pages/homes
/pages/homes/main.js
/pages/homes/new.js
/pages/homes/pay.js
```

Comment: Which version of Next are you using?

Comment: "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "^1.18.3",
    "cookie-session": "^2.0.0-beta.3",
    "express": "^4.16.3",
    "fs-extra": "^7.0.0",
    "ganache-cli": "^6.1.6",
    "mocha": "^5.2.0",
    "mongoose": "^5.2.4",
    "next": "^6.1.1",
    "next-routes": "^1.4.2",
    "passport": "^0.4.0",
    "passport-google-oauth20": "^1.0.0",
    "react": "^16.4.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.4.1",
    "semantic-ui-react": "^0.82.0",
    "solc": "^0.4.24",
    "truffle-hdwallet-provider": "0.0.5",
    "web3": "^1.0.0-beta.26"
  }